# How to return a thenable object that really works

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a thenable object that returns a value, but isn't working:

```js
const fetchItem = () => 'item';
function test() {
  return {
    async then() {
      const item = await fetchItem()
      return item
    }
  }
}

test()
  .then(console.log)
```

The then is being called, but the console.log it isn't. Any ideias why?

Comment: Is it just an exercise? Because async function already returns a promise which is, by coincidence, thenable.

Comment: you do realise by setting `async` on  `then` this function will return a native promise ... *snap* @estus :p

Comment: I do Jaramanda.. that's why I was struggling to understand why the then was not being called.

Comment: @estus That's not an exercise, I need to return a thenable object from a function... because I want have the option to get the item using then, but  also set other options before calling then, for example: func(arguments).setSpace(....).doThis(....).then() or use .end((error, data) => {}) instead of .then.

Comment: Then you have a problem here because async function shouldn't be used like that. It could be a promise augmented with `end` method or so. Another problem is that the promise is lazily executed and it's executed every time `then` is called, this is incorrect implementation of a thenable. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think so... superagent, which is a huge library do exactly like that. I'm testing here and if I try to execute 2 times, it won't work, the then won't be called two times.

Comment: And on top of it, I'm not trying to return a Promise, I'm returning a thenable object, which is perfect valid according to the specification of Promises - https://promisesaplus.com/

Comment: @ALOKX This is a thing I always considered weird about it. And it doesn't execute a promise twice, https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/request-base.js#L232 . `async` function doesn't really help here because it needs additional wrapper function to get a promise from it. I'd suggest to stick to raw promises here and make `then` a regular function.

Comment: @estus Well... I think is easier if I show what I'm doing: I want to be able to use a asyncIterator to get a status of a resource in (polling) my API, or a await to only get the item after the status is DONE: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKGWxL?editors=0010

Comment: Now I can do: `const { data } = await resource(data)` to get the resource if the status is `DONE`, or use `for await (const { status } of resource(data)) { console.log(status) }`. Maybe there are some problem that you can point out.

Comment: Unfortunately the [async operation proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) don't cover this :/, and I wan't give full control power for the caller, that's why I'm not using an EventEmitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then` should be a function that accepts a callback as a parameter - your `then` definition doesn't have one.

```js
function test() {
  return {
    async then(callback) {
      const item = await '3';
      return callback(item);
    }
  }
}
test()
  .then(console.log)
  .then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: oh, that makes a lot of sense!